# how to write XSLT to repeat a sibling nodes value with every occurence of its sibling in a HTML table

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLT so pardon me if my code is terrible. I would like to have a table in HTML with the episode details repeated for every daily intervention. At the momemt with my code I dont even have a table. I have looked for ways to do this but with no avail

My XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="example_XMLTransformationFile.xsl"?>
<ClientImport xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<episode localID="P333456">
    <episodeDetails>
        <caseNo>0000000</caseNo>
        <address1>where Person1 live</address1>
        <address4>Do they live there</address4>
        <postcode>PP1 2PP</postcode>
        <familyName>Person1</familyName>
        <firstName>PersonF1</firstName>
        <dobEst>0</dobEst>
    </episodeDetails>
    <dailyInterventions>
    <dailyIntervention>
        <activityDate>2012-08-23</activityDate>
        <ecg>true</ecg>
        <cpox>true</cpox>
        <invVentET>true</invVentET>
        <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
    </dailyIntervention>
    <dailyIntervention>
        <activityDate>2012-08-24</activityDate>
        <ecg>true</ecg>
        <cpox>true</cpox>
        <invVentET>true</invVentET>
        <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
    </dailyIntervention>
    <dailyIntervention>
        <activityDate>2012-08-25</activityDate>
        <ecg>true</ecg>
        <cpox>true</cpox>
        <invVentET>false</invVentET>
        <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
    </dailyIntervention>
    <dailyIntervention>
        <activityDate>2012-08-26</activityDate>
        <ecg>true</ecg>
        <cpox>true</cpox>
        <invVentET>true</invVentET>
        <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
    </dailyIntervention>
    <dailyIntervention>
        <activityDate>2012-08-27</activityDate>
        <ecg>true</ecg>
        <cpox>true</cpox>
        <invVentET>true</invVentET>
        <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
    </dailyIntervention>
    <dailyIntervention>
        <activityDate>2012-08-28</activityDate>
        <ecg>true</ecg>
        <cpox>true</cpox>
        <invVentET>true</invVentET>
        <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
    </dailyIntervention>
    <dailyIntervention>
        <activityDate>2012-08-29</activityDate>
        <ecg>true</ecg>
        <cpox>true</cpox>
        <invVentET>true</invVentET>
        <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
    </dailyIntervention>
    <dailyIntervention>
        <activityDate>2012-08-30</activityDate>
        <ecg>true</ecg>
        <cpox>true</cpox>
        <invVentET>false</invVentET>
        <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
    </dailyIntervention>
    <dailyIntervention>
        <activityDate>2012-08-31</activityDate>
        <ecg>true</ecg>
        <cpox>true</cpox>
        <invVentET>false</invVentET>
        <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
    </dailyIntervention>
    </dailyInterventions>
</episode>
<episode localID="20120410">
    <episodeDetails>
        <caseNo>0000001</caseNo>
        <address1>where Person2 Lives</address1>
        <address4>Street Person2</address4>
        <postcode>XX1 1XX</postcode>
        <familyName>Person2</familyName>
        <firstName>Person2 A</firstName>
        <dobEst>0</dobEst>
    </episodeDetails>
    <dailyInterventions>
    <dailyIntervention>
        <activityDate>2012-08-23</activityDate>
        <noCrit>true</noCrit>
    </dailyIntervention>
    </dailyInterventions>
</episode>
<episode localID="20120411">
<episodeDetails>
    <caseNo>0000002</caseNo>
    <address1>Where Person3 Lives</address1>
    <address4>Person 3 Street</address4>
    <postcode>WW1 1WW</postcode>
    <familyName>Person3</familyName>
    <firstName>Person 3 B</firstName>
    <dobEst>0</dobEst>
</episodeDetails>
<dailyInterventions>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-08-24</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>true</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-08-25</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>true</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-08-26</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>true</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-08-27</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>false</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-08-28</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>false</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-08-29</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>false</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
</dailyInterventions>
</episode>
<episode localID="20120418">
<episodeDetails>
    <caseNo>000004</caseNo>
    <address1>where person4 lives</address1>
    <address4>Person4 Road</address4>
    <postcode>NN1 1NN</postcode>
    <familyName>Person4</familyName>
    <firstName>Person4 B</firstName>
    <dobEst>0</dobEst>
</episodeDetails>
<dailyInterventions>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-08-24</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>false</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
</dailyInterventions>
</episode>
<episode localID="20120419">
<episodeDetails>
    <caseNo>0000005</caseNo>
    <address1>Where Person5 Lives</address1>
    <address4>Person5 Road</address4>
    <postcode>SS1 1SS</postcode>
    <familyName>Person5</familyName>
    <firstName>Person5 K</firstName>
    <dobEst>0</dobEst>
</episodeDetails>
<dailyInterventions>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-08-25</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>false</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-08-26</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>false</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-08-27</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>false</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-08-28</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>false</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-08-29</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>false</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-08-30</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>false</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-08-31</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>false</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-09-01</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>false</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-09-02</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>false</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-09-03</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>false</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
</dailyInterventions>
</episode>
<episode localID="20120420">
<episodeDetails>
    <caseNo>0000006</caseNo>
    <address1>Where person6 Lives</address1>
    <address4>Person6 Road</address4>
    <postcode>EE1 EE1</postcode>
    <familyName>Person6</familyName>
    <firstName>Person6 N</firstName>
    <dobEst>0</dobEst>
</episodeDetails>
<dailyInterventions>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-08-23</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>false</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-08-24</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>false</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-08-25</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>false</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-08-26</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>false</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
<dailyIntervention>
    <activityDate>2012-08-27</activityDate>
    <ecg>true</ecg>
    <cpox>true</cpox>
    <invVentET>false</invVentET>
    <invVentTT>false</invVentTT>
</dailyIntervention>
</dailyInterventions>
</episode>
```

My XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">     
        <html>    
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ClientImport"/>       
        </html> 
    </xsl:template> 
    <xsl:template match="ClientImport">     
        <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>LOCALID</th>
            <th>CASENO</th>
            <th>ADDRESS1</th>
            <th>ADDRESS4</th>
            <th>POSTCODE</th>
            <th>FAMILYNAME</th>
            <th>FIRSTNAME</th>
            <th>DOBEST</th>
            <th>ACTIVITYDATE</th>
            <th>ECG</th>
            <th>CPOX</th>
            <th>INVVENTET</th>
            <th>INVVENTTT</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="episode"/>                 
    </table>         
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="episode"> 
    <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@localID"/></td> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="dailyInterventions/dailyIntervention"/> 
    </tr>       
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="episodeDetails">       
        <td><xsl:value-of select="caseNo"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="address1"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="address4"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="postcode"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="familyName"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="firstName"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="dobEst"/></td>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="dailyInterventions/dailyIntervention"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates select="episodeDetails"> 
    <xsl:for-each select="dailyInterventions/dailyIntervention">
    <tr>

    <td><xsl:value-of select="activityDate"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="ecg"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="cpox"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="invVentET"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="invVentTT"/></td>
    </tr>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Desired Output

```
localID caseNo  address1    address4    postcode    familyName  firstName   dobEst  activityDate    ecg cpox    invVentET   invVentTT   noCrit
P333456 0   where Person1 live  Do they live there  PP1 2PP Person1 PersonF1    0   23/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   
P333456 0   where Person1 live  Do they live there  PP1 2PP Person1 PersonF1    0   24/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   
P333456 0   where Person1 live  Do they live there  PP1 2PP Person1 PersonF1    0   25/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   
P333456 0   where Person1 live  Do they live there  PP1 2PP Person1 PersonF1    0   26/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   
P333456 0   where Person1 live  Do they live there  PP1 2PP Person1 PersonF1    0   27/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   
P333456 0   where Person1 live  Do they live there  PP1 2PP Person1 PersonF1    0   28/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   
P333456 0   where Person1 live  Do they live there  PP1 2PP Person1 PersonF1    0   29/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   
P333456 0   where Person1 live  Do they live there  PP1 2PP Person1 PersonF1    0   30/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   
P333456 0   where Person1 live  Do they live there  PP1 2PP Person1 PersonF1    0   31/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   
20120410    1   where Person2 Lives Street Person2  XX1 1XX Person2 Person2 A   0   23/08/2012                  TRUE
20120411    2   Where Person3 Lives Person 3 Street WW1 1WW Person3 Person 3 B  0   24/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   
20120411    2   Where Person3 Lives Person 3 Street WW1 1WW Person3 Person 3 B  0   25/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   
20120411    2   Where Person3 Lives Person 3 Street WW1 1WW Person3 Person 3 B  0   26/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   
20120411    2   Where Person3 Lives Person 3 Street WW1 1WW Person3 Person 3 B  0   27/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   
20120411    2   Where Person3 Lives Person 3 Street WW1 1WW Person3 Person 3 B  0   28/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   
20120411    2   Where Person3 Lives Person 3 Street WW1 1WW Person3 Person 3 B  0   29/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   
20120418    4   where person4 lives Person4 Road    NN1 1NN Person4 Person4 B   0   24/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   
20120419    5   Where Person5 Lives Person5 Road    SS1 1SS Person5 Person5 K   0   25/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   
20120419    5   Where Person5 Lives Person5 Road    SS1 1SS Person5 Person5 K   0   26/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   
20120419    5   Where Person5 Lives Person5 Road    SS1 1SS Person5 Person5 K   0   27/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   
20120419    5   Where Person5 Lives Person5 Road    SS1 1SS Person5 Person5 K   0   28/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   
20120419    5   Where Person5 Lives Person5 Road    SS1 1SS Person5 Person5 K   0   29/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   
20120419    5   Where Person5 Lives Person5 Road    SS1 1SS Person5 Person5 K   0   30/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   
20120419    5   Where Person5 Lives Person5 Road    SS1 1SS Person5 Person5 K   0   31/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   
20120419    5   Where Person5 Lives Person5 Road    SS1 1SS Person5 Person5 K   0   01/09/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   
20120419    5   Where Person5 Lives Person5 Road    SS1 1SS Person5 Person5 K   0   02/09/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   
20120419    5   Where Person5 Lives Person5 Road    SS1 1SS Person5 Person5 K   0   03/09/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   
20120420    6   Where person6 Lives Person6 Road    EE1 EE1 Person6 Person6 N   0   23/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   
20120420    6   Where person6 Lives Person6 Road    EE1 EE1 Person6 Person6 N   0   24/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   
20120420    6   Where person6 Lives Person6 Road    EE1 EE1 Person6 Person6 N   0   25/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   
20120420    6   Where person6 Lives Person6 Road    EE1 EE1 Person6 Person6 N   0   26/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE   
20120420    6   Where person6 Lives Person6 Road    EE1 EE1 Person6 Person6 N   0   27/08/2012  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following stylesheet produces what I believe the desired output is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:variable name="lower" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyzy'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="upper" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWYZY'"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">     
        <html>    
            <xsl:apply-templates select="ClientImport"/>       
        </html> 
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="ClientImport">     
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="episode[1]/@localID" mode="header"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="episode[1]/episodeDetails[1]/*" mode="header"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="episode[1]/dailyInterventions[1]/dailyIntervention[1]/*" mode="header"/>
            </tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="episode"/>                 
        </table>         
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|*" mode="header">
        <th><xsl:value-of select="translate(local-name(), $lower, $upper)"/></th>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="episode"> 
        <xsl:apply-templates select="dailyInterventions/dailyIntervention"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@localID">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="episodeDetails">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="../@localID"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="dailyInterventions/dailyIntervention"> 
        <tr>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="../preceding-sibling::episodeDetails" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
        </tr>     
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="episodeDetails/* | dailyIntervention/*">
        <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I changed some of the boiler-plate hard-coded items to use `xsl:apply-templates`.

For instance, to generate the headers it applies templates for the attribute and elements in a mode that creates the `<th>` and outputs the upper-case name of the item.

Comment: Thanks gives the desired output, although  has some slight problems which I will try to iron out and get back here if not solved

Comment: What problems? It is helpful if you post example output to aid in understanding and ensure useful answers.

Comment: I am new to the forum as well and learning my way round. Been tryng to attach the output to no avail. The problem (which is slight), is that when a new episode is output the episode details are output first and they do not alighn with the headers. I have tried to copy a sample of the output data below.                            LOCALID CASENO ADDRESS1 ADDRESS4 POSTCODE FAMILYNAME FIRSTNAME DOBEST ACTIVITYDATE ECG CPOx INVVENTET INVVENTTT 
0000000 where Person1 live Do they live there PP1 2PP Person1 PersonF1 0 
P333456 0000000 where Person1 live Do they live there PP1 2PP

Comment: I had a mistake in my templates. I have updated the answer. Please re-run and verify output. In the template for `episodes` I was incorrectly applying templates for `episodeDetails`, which was creating the row with incomplete columns. `episodeDetails` gets transformed inside of the template match for each `dailyIntervention`, which repeats the `episodeDetails` info for each row.

Answer (score 0):

I would just go by dailyIntervention elements and for each found one insert a row into the table. All the fields that are not available in the dailyIntervention node can be accessed via xpath's expression .. for parent.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="ClientImport">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
<table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>LOCALID</th><th>CASENO</th><th>ADDRESS1</th><th>ADDRESS4</th><th>POSTCODE</th><th>FAMILYNAME</th><th>FIRSTNAME</th><th>DOBEST</th><th>ACTIVITYDATE</th><th>ECG</th><th>CPOX</th><th>INVVENTET</th><th>INVVENTTT</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//dailyIntervention"/>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="dailyIntervention">
<tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./../../@localID"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./../../episodeDetails/caseNo"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./../../episodeDetails/address1"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./../../episodeDetails/address4"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./../../episodeDetails/postcode"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./../../episodeDetails/familyName"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./../../episodeDetails/firstName"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./../../episodeDetails/dobEst"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./activityDate"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./ecg"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./cpox"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./invVentET"/></td>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="./invVentTT"/></td>
</tr>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```